# Error install binwrap with yarn on Mac OS Monterey with M1 chip

Tags: yarnpkg, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I am facing this issue while installing `binwrap` with yarn. Please, find the log below:

```
error /Users/.../client/node_modules/elmi-to-json: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: binwrap-install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/.../client/node_modules/elmi-to-json
Output:
/Users/.../client/node_modules/elmi-to-json/node_modules/binwrap/install.js:18
throw new Error("No binaries are available for your platform: " + buildId);
^

Error: No binaries are available for your platform: darwin-arm64
at install (/Users/.../client/node_modules/elmi-to-json/node_modules/binwrap/install.js:18:11)
at Object.install (/Users/.../client/node_modules/elmi-to-json/node_modules/binwrap/index.js:14:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../client/node_modules/elmi-to-json/node_modules/binwrap/bin/binwrap-install:18:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue building an elm app on M1. I opened an issue here
https://github.com/avh4/binwrap/issues/63